# SUM on a left joined column is limiting results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query for a few testing tables:

```
SELECT salesperson.spnum, salesperson.spname, sales.quantity
FROM salesperson
LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.spnum = salesperson.spnum;
```

This returns the following results:

```
spnum   spname  quantity
1   "Bob Jansen"    5
1   "Bob Jansen"    10
1   "Bob Jansen"    1600
2   "Henk de Vries" NULL
3   "Anne de Graaf" NULL
```

However, when I use a `SUM()` for the select:

```
SELECT salesperson.spnum, salesperson.spname, SUM(sales.quantity) AS quantity
FROM salesperson
LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.spnum = salesperson.spnum;
```

I only get results from rows where the `quantity` column is not null:

```
spnum   spname  quantity
1   "Bob Jansen"    1615
```

How do I prevent `SUM()` from limiting my results like this? I would like to get either NULL or "0" as quantity.

Comment: `GROUP BY salesperson.spnum, salesperson.spname` is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting what is happening.

When you add a `SUM()` to your original query, you are turning the query into an aggregation query.  An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` *always* returns exactly one row (even if the original tables have no rows).  The `SUM()` is the `SUM()` of *all* columns.

In most databases, your code would return an error, because there are columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  MySQL does support this syntax -- although my advice is basically to never use it.

The solution is simple:  Add the appropriate `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT sp.spnum, sp.spname, SUM(s.quantity) AS quantity
FROM salesperson sp LEFT JOIN
     sales s
     ON s.spnum = sp.spnum
GROUP BY sp.spnum, sp.spname;
```

Notice that I added table aliases to your query.  This makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: This clarifies a lot, I had no idea. And yes, I should have used aliases (though I respectfully disagree with the usage of one or two-letter aliases).

Answer (score 1):

Add a group by (which this should have to run anyways)

```
SELECT salesperson.spnum, salesperson.spname, SUM(sales.quantity) AS quantity FROM salesperson
LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.spnum = salesperson.spnum
GROUP BY salesperson.spnum, salesperson.spname;
```

This should then show them even if null